# How to remove HTML5 title attribute after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hybrid-mobile-app, icenium

I am using html 5 for mobile development in Icenium.

I want to do validation so I used **required** attribute along with **title** attribute to show messages to user.

But once I do enter correct input into the specified fields that title messages should get remove; as it won't be appropriate to show messages to user once they enter appropriate values.

I want to remove titles form fields after validation, is there any way for this?

```
<li>
    <label>First Name:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" required title="Please Enter your First Name">
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Last Name:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" required title="Please Enter your Last Name">
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Email:
        <input type="email" required title="please enter your email" data-bind="value: emailAddress" autocomplete="off">
    </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li>
    <label>First Name:
        <input class="txtCheck" type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" required title="Please Enter your First Name">
    </label>
</li>


$('.txtCheck').on('blur keyup', function(){
      if($(this).val() == "yourvalue"){
         $(this).removeAttr('title');
      }
});
```

Comment: i want to remove title just after user enters the correct input and not after submitting the value on submit of button

Comment: suppose First Name is required field and user needs to put some name into it so after that i want to remove the title attribute of First Name field

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rely on HTML5 functionality, then I’d suggest making use of the [constraint validation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api).

`element.willValidate`, `element.validity.valid` or `element.checkValidity()` are what you could query upon the blur event (or change, keyup, whatever) to see if a certain element is currently in valid state or not.